# “in where I live” vs “where I live in”

Tags: grammar

The house, in where I live, is on fire. vs The house, where I live in, is on fire.

Which one is correct? I have read somewhere that if you want to add a modifier to the sentence, the preposition (in this case, "in") has to be in the front. Is this correct? It sounds so weird.

Edit: I posted this before here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553795/in-where-i-live-vs-where-i-live-in
and got recommended to repost here. I posted here again since I still feel a little uncleared about "in where I live."
Have there ever been any mentions of it before? Or is it plain 'wrong' like how the comment from the post I have posted in english.stackexchange.com mentioned?

Comment: You already received answers and comments at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553795/in-where-i-live-vs-where-i-live-in -- at a minimum you should acknowledge the information you already received and explain what was still unclear.

Comment: *Where* is wrong in both cases.  "The house where I live" or "the house which I live in" or perhaps somewhat more marginally "the house in which I live" would be grammatical.

Comment: @tripleee done!

Comment: "Where" already incorporates the "in" meaning, so there is no need to repeat it. You need either "The house where I live" or "The house that/which I live in" or slightly more formally "The house in which I live".